# Can I avoid creating a class here?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using .NET framework 2.0, and I have a situation where I have a class like:

```
class MyThing 
{
  private int val;
  private DateTime date;
  private Guid id;

  public MyThing(..) { ... }
}
```

The only reason this class exists is because at some point in my code, I need to keep track of a `List<MyThing>`. However, `MyThing` doesn't have any real purpose other than as a place to keep my data together in one method, so it feels ugly to create a class for this. I'd rather not create a `List<List<object>>` because this is ugly too.

Is there another way?

Comment: Don't you think keeping stuff together is enough of a purpose?

Comment: In .Net 2.0, I don't think there is.  A bunch of opportunities open up in .Net 4.0.

Comment: No, a class is meant for this. Encapsulation.

Comment: It's not 'ugly' to keep a class to hold something in a small scope. Just keep it simple and name it appropriately.

Comment: @zneak not really for a one off container that will never be used elsewhere and doesnt even make sense to give it a name

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: I'm pretty sure the version of the editor (Visual Studio) really doesn't matter in terms of language features (2.0 in this case)

Comment: @Chris .NET 2.0 isn't the language version, it's the framework version.  You can create a .NET 2.0 project in VS 2010 and use almost all the C# 4 language features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, a class is the right way to go.

Additionally, if you don't want to create a class just for the purpose of grouping these properties together, you might want to take a look at the `Tuple` class *<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)</sup>*. It was introduced in .NET 4.0, but it wouldn't be hard to recreate in .NET 2.0.

Basically, it is a generic class with a bunch of overloads that lets you group different objects together in a type safe way. Something like this:

```
public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you would use it like this:

```
Tuple<int, DateTime, Guid> myThing = new Tuple<int, DateTime, Guid>();
myThing.Item1 = 42;
myThing.Item2 = DateTime.Now;
myThing.Item3 = Guid.NewGuid();
```

This might not satifying your requirement to not be ugly, but at least it's reusable.

Answer (score 5):

Using a `class` (or perhaps a [`struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) is definitely the right way to go. Not sure why you think it feels ugly. That's the purpose. It defines "something" and in this case that something is whatever is represented by those three values that you want to keep a list of

Answer (score 3):

Why is it ugly? This is perfectly normal.

But I would agree, that by having correct class architecture, you should be able to avoid passing classes only as arguments between methods.

Comment: +1 - No idea who downvoted, but this is perfectly valid. The purpose of creating objects is to group together data and behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you test your code with FxCop with 'Microsoft All Rules' then using class the only right way.

Because

1. List< List< oject>> will generate warning
2. Tuple is also not a good practice. You do not know what Item1, Item2 in Tuple denote. Also you will not get the IntelliSense of its types.
3. In either way you are creating reference types so there is no change in performance
4. MainClass and the inside class has 'has-a' relation which cannot be understood if you use tuple of list of list.
5. Creating different class is the best practice to increase readability and to keep clean code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of Visual Studio 2008 or better (regardless of whether you're targeting .NET 2.0), you could use anonymous types and do something like this without having to declare a class:

```
static List<T> CreateList<T>(IEnumerable<T> stuff)
{
    return new List<T>(stuff);
}

static IEnumerable<T> SubSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    foreach (var item in sequence)
        if (predicate(item)) yield return item;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = CreateList(new[]
                            {
                            new {val = 1,
                                date = DateTime.Now,
                                id = Guid.NewGuid()},
                            new {val = 2, 
                                date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                                id = Guid.NewGuid()}
                            });

    var subset = SubSet(list, item=>item.val == 1);
}
```